Math behind the standardized effects from Minitab
I would like to understand the mathematics behind the Standardized effects (SE) as found in, e.g., Minitab. I'm far from an expert in statistics, but I found this page which treats the same question. However, the accepted answer only shows how to calculate the SE for the main effects A, B, and C etc. The SE is defined as the difference between the average of all the responses at the +1 level and -1 level for each parameter. What I would still like to know is how to calculate the SE (Effect and Coeff) for the cross-terms such as A*B, and even A*B*C. How does one define the +1 and -1 levels for cross-terms? Perhaps if someone could just point me to a good reference, e.g., a book?
